# How to convert simple Url to well formated Url in c# 7?

Tags: c#, url, uri, converters

How to convert simple URL to well formed URL in C# 7?

From:
`google.com` or
`www.google.com`

To:
`http://www.google.com`

OR

From:
`mail.google.com` or
`www.mail.google.com`

To:
`http://www.mail.google.com`

Comment: Do you object to `http://google.com` for some reason? That's a perfectly well-formed URL.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok for you?

```cs
var result = url.StartsWith("www.") ? $"http://{url}" : $"http://www.{url}";
```

Comment: What if the url starts with http://www.? Or if the url is wwwxxx.example.com?

Comment: In that case, I would use `url.StartsWith("www.")`, thanks for your example. (answer updated)